# match enum by range

Tags: enums, rust

I wonder if it is possible to use a range matcher with an enum. Toy example:

```
enum Things {
    One,
    Two,
    Three
}

pub fn main() {
    match One {
        One...Two => println!("one to two"),
        Three => println!("three")
    }
}
```

Error:

```
<anon>:9:9: 9:12 error: only char and numeric types are allowed in range [E0029]
<anon>:9         One...Two => println!("one to two"),
                 ^~~
error: aborting due to previous error
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
```

http://is.gd/rxKMfk

So, is it possible to make something like this work?

Comment: Not what you are asking, but you can match two enums in the same arm: `One | Two => ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really. Enums aren't ordered. You can, however, do:

```
enum Things {
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3
}

pub fn main() {
    match One as uint {
        1..2 => println!("one to two"),
        3 => println!("three")
    }
}
```